# How to silence selenium/chromedriver logs

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, webdriver-manager

I am using selenium 4 with webdriver manager, running tests headless on chrome. I want to silence logs. I looked through similiar questions and I managed to silence few logs by adding code below, but I still receive a few, which is annoying when running tests in parallel.

I put `Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.SEVERE)` in before method and this is my method to create driver:

```
    @Override
    public WebDriver createDriverHeadless() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().cachePath("drivers").setup();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentLogging", "true");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
        options.setHeadless(true);
        options.addArguments(
                "--disable-gpu",
                "--window-size=1920,1080",
                "--ignore-certificate-errors",
                "--disable-extensions",
                "--no-sandbox",
                "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
                "--log-level=3"
        );
        return new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
```

yet, I cant get rid of these logs:

[image: logs]

How can I silence these?

Answer (score 1):

You get rid of these logs by adding the following *experimental_option*:

```
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-logging"));
```

Comment: I added your option, however I still get the same red messages :(